# cluster and partition on postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.3, database-partitioning, clustered-index

I have a table with 200.000.000 rows and I'd like to reduce the size of this table. I want to use partition and cluster. So my question is:
Can I use cluster on a partitioned table in postgresql

Note: I use postgresql9.3 and ubuntu 24.04 as os

Comment: This sort of question is better off on dba.stackexchange.com, but please try to be more specific.

Comment: There is a pretty good video on PostgreSQL partitioning here: https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-partitioning-by-simon-riggs-full-webinar-video/, but 9.3 is quite old, consider using v12 or higher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about table partitioning and the `CLUSTER` command:

You can `CLUSTER` a partitioned table, but it'll only affect the parent table. If you want to `CLUSTER` all the sub-tables you have to do each individually. Some PL/PgSQL to generate the SQL statements and `EXECUTE` them can be useful for this.

Comment: Just thought I might add that clustering does NOT seem to be allowed at all on declarative partition parent tables. I got:
`ERROR: cannot cluster a partitioned table SQL state: 0A000`